# Will Firebase sync offline data after logout on reconnection?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, synchronization

I have a scenario where offline data is lost, but it seems it should have synced to the server.

**Scenario:**

A user is logged into our Firebase application. Persistence is turned on as suggested by Firebase:

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

If the user kills the app and restarts it while offline, he/she can continue using the app to create and query the data offline. When the user regains a network connection, the data will sync. We are good to that point.

However, if the user logs out of the app while offline, he/she will need to regain a network connection to log in. At that time the app will get a new authentication token. But the data that was previously saved with the first login session/token while offline has not yet synced. Is that data lost? or is there a way to tell Firebase to synchronize that offline data using the previous or new token?

[image: timeline of sync]

**tl;dr:**

How do you get firebase data that was created offline prior to logout, to sync once there is a connection?

Note: I am not using trasactions. I am aware that transactions are lost on restart of the app.

Comment: Is the lost data protected by security rules?

Comment: No. If the user has not logged out, on reconnection the data does sync. Edit: there are no rules related to this data.

Comment: If what you are getting at is that the data might be deleted from the device before it can sync, no, the data is not removed. It just never makes it to the server.

Comment: To clarify my comments above, yes, my rules require a user to be authenticated to read/write data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working with support at Firebase, this is what I learned. The following is true if you have security rules that require a user to be authenticated.

Data collected offline requires the authentication token in order to replicate data back to the server once a connection is obtained. The firebase.auth().signOut() command destroys the token, and so the user's data is lost.

In order to avoid losing data, you must either prevent your app from logging off, or separately store offline data on your own, and provide a way to get that data to resubmit/sync to firebase on the new authentication token.

This is an area where hopefully Firebase will improve. My thought was that Firebase should sync data based on the token used when the user was still logged in. Just because the user has logged off, he/she was logged in at the time of the data collection, even though the user was offline. I was told this would be a feature request.